Why can't I install an APK only on Android TV?
I have an APK made with Unreal Engine 5.4.4 and installed it on several smartphones and tablets (since versions Android 10.0 until Android 14.0), and it all works.
But when I try to install it on an Android TV, I receive an error that says the app isn't compatible with the device or Android version, which is 11.0 and I've already installed it on Android 11.0 devices successfully, except the TV. Does anyone know why it is happening and what can I do to install it on TV successfully?
I've tried a lot of different build configs on Unreal, but none of them works on the TV and just the TV.

what does your manifest look like

Try to install the APK via adb install the you will get an error message explaining what you can not install APK.
